# Displaying one content item at two different URLs

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Our navigation looks like this:

```
Item1    Item2    Item3
-Sub1    -Sub3    -Sub4
-Sub2    -Sub2    -Sub5
```

As you can see, Sub2 is repeated under Item1 and Item2.

On each page (Sub*), we have side navigation (added using Widget Layer Rules) that shows the entire navigation under the main-menu item.  So, if you're on Sub1, you would see Sub1 and Sub2 on the side nav.

The problem is that we want to show the right side nav for Sub2 based on the menu item through which the user accesses the page.  We could [create a new Widget Layer based on the URL](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets), but we would still need to be able to display the page at two different URLs.  We don't want to replicate the page, since that wouldn't scale very well for maintaining these pages.  Is there a way to display one content item at two URLs, or is this something that needs to be built custom?

Comment: You should not do that. One resource should have one URL. Doing otherwise is going to hurt SEO, and it goes against basic HTTP principles.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Do you have a recommendation?  We could replicate the content to be able to know which side nav to display, but that's really the same thing.  I suppose we could have query strings to show which side nav to display, but that would be confusing (Item1/Sub2?Nav=Item2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Modules page and enable the Alias UI feature, you can add aliases for routes within your application. This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to choose which link is shown when I select the Content Item, or do I have to use a custom link?

Comment: In the menu? Use the custom link feature?

Comment: Right - was wondering if there was a way to link to the Content Item instead of directly to the Alias.  Either way, though, this is what I needed, so thanks!